Is Inline Styling Part of the CSSOM or the DOM?
I'm trying to understand the relationship between inline styles and the CSS Object Model (CSSOM) in a web document. Specifically, I want to know if inline styles applied directly to an element (either via HTML style attributes or JavaScript's element.style) are part of the CSSOM or handled by the DOM.
Inline styles are applied directly to an element, like this:
<div style="color: blue; font-size: 20px;">This text is styled with inline CSS.</div>

or using JavaScript:
const element = document.getElementById("myElement");
element.style.color = "blue";
element.style.fontSize = "20px";

My question is:

Do these inline styles become part of the CSSOM or are they stored separately within the DOM?
Are inline styles accessible via CSSOM APIs like document.styleSheets or only through the style property of the element?
Is there any authoritative source (specification, documentation) that clearly explains this distinction?

My understanding is:

Inline styles are not included in the CCSOM.
CSSOM does include all the css rules included in all external stylesheets (<link>), internal styles (<style> tags) and dynamically added rules using JavaScript (e.g., insertRule()). It does not filter them out and it is not its responsibility to emerge the winner with the highest precedence. It simply attaches all the corresponding css properties to the appropriate tree nodes, even the conflicting ones.
The browser applies the cascade rule taking into account the DOM and the CSSOM. The final computed value for every css property and for every element is knowledge that belongs only to the DOM and CSSOM is not aware of.

Do you think I am wrong or correct? I've seen conflicting explanations, and I’d like to get a concrete answer with references if possible. Any clarification on whether inline styling is officially considered part of the CSSOM or just contributes to the computed styles would be helpful.

Where do you place the distinction between DOM and CSSOM, and why do you think there is a hard line at all?

Have you looked at the spec?

The spec for the style attribute clearly lays out

The style IDL attribute is defined in CSS Object Model. [CSSOM]

In can be found in chapter 7 DOM Access to CSS Declaration Blocks therein.

Your answer is vague and hence not helpful. Inline styles are definitely part of the DOM. Does the above mean they are part of the CSSOM as well?

How is this vague? It gives the authoritative source that the HTMLElement.style API is defined as part of the CSSOM.

So, it is part of the CSSOM and the DOM?

It is not part of the DOM specification at all, which refers to CSSOM only. But sure, CSSOM specifies ElementCSSInlineStyle as a mixin for the DOM HTMLElement interface. As for the browser implementation, there's no distinction at all, it's all in the same environment without any gaps or trying to assign particular objects in areas.
